# Area light rectangle can be seen in window reflection - cycles

Tags: light, glass, reflection

I have little problem. My light source (area light) can be seen in window reflection
Is there any fix for it. I want to keep light, reflections and everything but without that ugly thing in window[image: glass texture][image: arealight location]

Comment: Try increasing the Roughness of the glass material.  You have Roughness of Glass BDSF set to '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many formulations for glass.  I'm attaching a blend file with an alternative:

[image]

that adds roughness to the glass to soften/blur reflections

[image]

you can disable any reflection by changing the second Mix Shader to factor=0.

I left a variation on your material as "Adrian Glass Edited" that you can switch in [image]

Although, in my opinion, glass generally is reflective of light!

Answer (score 0):

This is inherent. Try using some other form of light source instead, such as emissive material or an array of point lights.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest method to remove the light reflection is unchecking
the multiple importance button,

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure if unchecking multiple importance will cause other problems,
but in my experience, it never happens.